# WebGoat springboot java app - not logging http status code in console

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, webgoat

I am using https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat, trying to change couple of configs below but none works. I am not expert in Java so hope to have some insights what's wrong in my config.

1. What I want to achieve: logging http status code in console / any log driver
   when i execute the app, there are some logs appeared in the terminal but I want the http status code 200 or 302 etc whenever we access the pages.

For example, when I access `http://127.0.0.1:8080/WebGoat`, there should be http code 302 with a redirect. Or when I refresh on http://127.0.0.1:8080/login, there should be http code 200 like what I got from `curl -i http://127.0.0.1:8080/login`

What I did: i have updated the `application.properties` file logging sections to DEBUG level

```
logging.level.org.thymeleaf=DEBUG
logging.level.org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.CONFIG=DEBUG
logging.level.org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.TIMER=DEBUG
logging.level.org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.cache.TEMPLATE_CACHE=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.devtools=DEBUG
logging.level.org.owasp=DEBUG
logging.level.org.owasp.webgoat=DEBUG
logging.level.org.owasp.webgoat=DEBUG
```

However none of these appear when I access the page from browser. The logs merely shows actions of initialization, further refresh or accessing the page doesn't log any status code:

```
2023-04-13 17:02:30.794  INFO 69552 --- [           main] 

o.s.b.w.e.undertow.UndertowWebServer     : Undertow started on port(s) 9090 (http)
2023-04-13 17:02:30.804  INFO 69552 --- [           main] org.owasp.webgoat.server.StartWebGoat    : Started StartWebGoat in 0.653 seconds (JVM running for 10.763)
2023-04-13 17:02:30.805  INFO 69552 --- [           main] org.owasp.webgoat.server.StartupMessage  : Please browse to http://127.0.0.1:8080/WebGoat to get started...
2023-04-13 17:02:59.997  INFO 69552 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] io.undertow.servlet                      : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-04-13 17:02:59.997  INFO 69552 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-04-13 17:03:00.000  INFO 69552 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 3 ms
```

When I inspect the network on browser, I can see the status code (image) [image: browser network log shows status code]. What is missing here? If I need to add logging action `log.debug` somewhere, any guidance on that?

I have searched through those files in the main webgoat application, but a bit confused as where should i add further. I thought the application.properties file did configure logging with `logging.level.org.owasp=DEBUG` stated.

https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat/tree/main/src/main/java/org/owasp/webgoat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out - to add http code status logging, just add a `logback.xml` file with configuration:

```
<configuration>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
<logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG"/>
</configuration>
```

For the specific example with this https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat app, the location of the `logback.xml` file will be in the `src/main/resources/` folder.

(Note: some test cases will fail, but just proceed to reinstall and containerize it to execute after that as stated in the github steps :

```
# On Linux/Mac:
./mvnw clean install

# On Windows:
./mvnw.cmd clean install

# Using docker or podman, you can than build the container locally
docker build -f Dockerfile . -t webgoat/webgoat

Now we are ready to run the project. WebGoat is using Spring Boot.

# On Linux/Mac:
./mvnw spring-boot:run
# On Windows:
./mvnw.cmd spring-boot:run
```

And you will see the http code status logged after that when u run it locally or in chosen path.